# Why are some image textures omitted when I texture bake?

Tags: texturing, materials, image, texture-baking, baking

I have a large object with multiple materials, some of which use image textures.  I am trying to bake them all into one.  For the most part, it works perfectly.  However, a select few images do not bake properly, without any rhyme or reason.  I.E. sometimes textures A and B will bake perfectly while C and D won't, and other times textures B and C will work while A and D don't.

Note: some of the textures do have transparency in them, but even still, not all of these "transparent" textures have issues

Example, before: [image: before bake]

After: [image: after bake]

Here's the shader nodes of one texture that didn't work.[image: nodes]

And here's what the bake looks like, with some red marks I added where there are notable holes. [image: bake]

And finally here are my bake settings.
[image: bake settings]

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**  After baking once, with errors, I went back into the shader node trees of the errored textures, and simply readded the texture image to the corresponding nodes, and baked again.